# Split and Save individual powerpoint slide with the name in notes VBA

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I would like to split my PowerPoint file such that each slide is saved as a separate PowerPoint file. I would like the name of each file to correspond with the text present in the notes section.

[This code](https://powerpointprogram.indezine.com/2019/10/powerpoint-vba-export-slides-to-single-slide-presentations.html) worked for splitting the PowerPoint file. What I would like to do now is to　name and save each slide with text located in note in each slide.

`.NotesPage.Shapes.Placeholders(2).TextFrame.TextRange`

This code snippet didn't work. I appreciate your guidance.

Comment: @SteveRindsberg Sorry for not enough info. It did not give any error messages. It did nothing without any error message.

Comment: Try adding .Text to your statement to get the text in the Text Range: ActivePresentation.Slides(1).NotesPage.Shapes(2).TextFrame.TextRange.Text

Comment: @JohnKorchok Thank you so much! It worked! I modified like following from the original one.
        tFileName = ActivePresentation.Slides(1).NotesPage.Shapes(2).TextFrame.TextRange.Text & ".pptx"
 .SaveCopyAs tPath & "\" & tFileName, ppSaveAsOpenXMLPresentation